# Asp.net mvc web api async request result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a web api controller action that sends a request to another server and gets an image.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{ 
   public async Runner<HttpResponseMessage> Wms()
   {
       return await Run();                                    
   }

   private Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run()
   {
       HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
       requestMessage.RequestUri = "http://....";

       foreach (var header in this.Request.Headers)
          requestMessage.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);

        return requestMessage.SendAsync();
   }
}
```

How can I get async request result of `requestMessage.SendAsync()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the async modifier to the method and `await SendAsync()`:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunAsync()
{
   HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
   requestMessage.RequestUri = "http://....";

   foreach (var header in this.Request.Headers)
      requestMessage.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);

   HttpResponseMessage response = await requestMessage.SendAsync();
   string resultData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Or if you want the response inside `Wms`, you can `await` that.

Comment: var response = await requestMessage.SendAsync(); response has not a propert named Result. So how can I get image result in it?

Comment: You're looking for `var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` or `ReadAsStreamAsync()`, whichever you want.